# Convert string to a variable name

Tags: string, r

I am using R to parse a list of strings in the form:

```
original_string <- "variable_name=variable_value"
```

First, I extract the variable name and value from the original string and convert the value to numeric class.

```
parameter_value <- as.numeric("variable_value")
parameter_name <- "variable_name"
```

Then, I would like to assign the value to a variable with the same name as the `parameter_name` string.

```
variable_name <- parameter_value
```

What is/are the function(s) for doing this?

Answer (score 148, accepted):

assign is what you are looking for.

```
assign("x", 5)

x
[1] 5
```

but buyer beware.

See R FAQ 7.21
http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-can-I-turn-a-string-into-a-variable_003f

Comment: “Buyer beware” is a rather blasé way of saying that you should almost never do this, because it’s almost never a good solution to a given problem.

Comment: Before using this solution, you might consider creating a list `parameter_list <- list()` and adding a value `paramter_list[parameter_name] <- parameter_value`.

Comment: This solution works for the current environment only. That means if you want to make the variable a global variable, you would need to put the statement somewhere it could be global. However, if your statement is inside a function but still want to make the variable global, [Adam's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034655/convert-string-to-a-variable-name/56929853#56929853) below would do the trick.

Answer (score 83):

You can use do.call:

```
 do.call("<-",list(parameter_name, parameter_value))
```

Comment: +1 for thinking.  People (me included) usually forget that `<-` is a function itself.

Answer (score 69):

There is another simple solution found there: 
http://www.r-bloggers.com/converting-a-string-to-a-variable-name-on-the-fly-and-vice-versa-in-r/

To convert a string to a variable:

```
x <- 42
eval(parse(text = "x"))
[1] 42
```

And the opposite:

```
x <- 42
deparse(substitute(x))
[1] "x"
```

Answer (score 39):

The function you are looking for is `get()`:

```
assign ("abc",5)
get("abc")
```

Confirming that the memory address is identical:

```
getabc <- get("abc")
pryr::address(abc) == pryr::address(getabc)
# [1] TRUE
```

Reference: [R FAQ 7.21 How can I turn a string into a variable?](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-can-I-turn-a-string-into-a-variable_003f)

Comment: Great! This is the most concise answer I found. Is there a similarly concise way to do the reverse? just like `x <- 42; deparse(substitute(x))`

Answer (score 24):

Use `x=as.name("string")`. You can use then use `x` to refer to the variable with name string.

I don't know, if it answers your question correctly.

Comment: `x=as.symbol("string")`

Answer (score 11):

`strsplit` to parse your input and, as Greg mentioned, `assign` to assign the variables.

```
original_string <- c("x=123", "y=456")
pairs <- strsplit(original_string, "=")
lapply(pairs, function(x) assign(x[1], as.numeric(x[2]), envir = globalenv()))
ls()
```

Answer (score 6):

`assign` is good, but I have not found a function for referring back to the variable you've created in an automated script.  (`as.name` seems to work the opposite way).  More experienced coders will doubtless have a better solution, but this solution works and is slightly humorous perhaps, in that it gets R to write code for itself to execute.

Say I have just assigned value 5 to `x` (`var.name <- "x"; assign(var.name, 5)`) and I want to change the value to 6.  If I am writing a script and don't know in advance what the variable name (`var.name`) will be (which seems to be the point of the `assign` function), I can't simply put `x <- 6` because `var.name` might have been `"y"`.  So I do:

```
var.name <- "x"
#some other code...
assign(var.name, 5)
#some more code...

#write a script file (1 line in this case) that works with whatever variable name
write(paste0(var.name, " <- 6"), "tmp.R")
#source that script file
source("tmp.R")
#remove the script file for tidiness
file.remove("tmp.R")
```

`x` will be changed to 6, and if the variable name was anything other than `"x"`, that variable will similarly have been changed to 6.

Answer (score 2):

I was working with this a few days ago, and noticed that sometimes you will need to use the `get()` function to print the results of your variable.
ie :

```
varnames = c('jan', 'feb', 'march')
file_names = list_files('path to multiple csv files saved on drive')
assign(varnames[1], read.csv(file_names[1]) # This will assign the variable
```

From there, if you try to print the variable `varnames[1]`, it returns 'jan'. 
To work around this, you need to do 
`print(get(varnames[1]))`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to convert string to variable inside body of function, but you want to have variable global:

```
test <- function() {
do.call("<<-",list("vartest","xxx"))
}
test()
vartest

[1] "xxx"
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I didn't understand your problem right, because of the simplicity of your example. To my understanding, you have a series of instructions stored in character vectors, and those instructions are very close to being properly formatted, except that you'd like to cast the right member to numeric.

If my understanding is right, I would like to propose a slightly different approach, that does not rely on splitting your original string, but directly evaluates your instruction (with a little improvement).

```
original_string <- "variable_name=\"10\"" # Your original instruction, but with an actual numeric on the right, stored as character.
library(magrittr) # Or library(tidyverse), but it seems a bit overkilled if the point is just to import pipe-stream operator
eval(parse(text=paste(eval(original_string), "%>% as.numeric")))
print(variable_name)
#[1] 10
```

Basically, what we are doing is that we 'improve' your instruction `variable_name="10"` so that it becomes `variable_name="10" %>% as.numeric`, which is an equivalent of `variable_name=as.numeric("10")` with `magrittr` pipe-stream syntax. Then we evaluate this expression within current environment.

Hope that helps someone who'd wander around here 8 years later ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Other than `assign`, one other way to assign value to string named object is to access `.GlobalEnv` directly.

```
# Equivalent
assign('abc',3)

.GlobalEnv$'abc' = 3
```

Accessing `.GlobalEnv` gives some flexibility, and my use case was assigning values to a string-named list. For example,

```
.GlobalEnv$'x' = list()
.GlobalEnv$'x'[[2]] = 5 # works

var = 'x'
.GlobalEnv[[glue::glue('{var}')]][[2]] = 5 # programmatic names from glue()
```

Answer (score 0):

For all those who want to assign a value to one variable within the dataset, I have another solution. What I tried to get, this is a situation where I have a set of data:

```
dataset <- data.frame(
    X = sample(1:10),
    Y = sample(c("yes", "no"), 10, replace = TRUE)
)
```

and I use the variable name to get the data from the one row of dataset and then modify it:

```
rowname <- "dataset$Y"
variable <- eval(str2lang(rowname))
variable [1] <- "dont know"
```

then, to correctly assign one variable/column within the dataset, the only thing that **WORKED** was:

```
do.call("<-",list(str2lang(rowname), variable))
```

and all of the following, DON'T, I repeat, DID NOT WORK:

```
eval(str2lang(rowname)) <- variable
str2lang(rowname) <- variable
eval(rowname) <- variable

assign(rowname, variable)
assign(eval(str2lang(rowname)), variable)

assign(variable, rowname)
assign(variable, eval(str2lang(rowname)))
```

I hope this will be useful to someone.