# how can i use a name (string) as variable?

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [R: How to convert string to variable name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034655/r-how-to-convert-string-to-variable-name)

If I do:

```
'a' = c(1:10)        
a
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

here I assign a vector to a string (variable)
but i need to a do something like:

```
a = 'c10'
```

and then

```
a = c(1:10)
```

but the last a must to be **c10**

How can i do it?

Comment: See `get`, `assign`, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679193/how-to-name-variables-on-the-fly-in-r , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034655/r-how-to-convert-string-to-variable-name

Comment: Also FAQ on R 7.21 http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-can-I-turn-a-string-into-a-variable_003f

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're looking for but your first assignment doesn't need the `c()` and doesn't need quotes around the `a`.

```
a <- 1:10
```

if you want the last entry to be the string 'c10', you can get there a few different ways.

```
a <- c(1:9,'c10')
```

or

```
a <- 1:10
a[10] <- 'c10'
```

Or if Ben Bolker is on the right track:

```
a <- 'c10'
assign(a,1:10)
```