# R: How to loop with "while" and attach variable in object name?

Tags: r

I need to make the following calculation:

a1= 100+1
a2 = 100+2
...
a10 = 100+10

I try to loop this as follows:

```
z = 1
while(z<11) {
    z = z+1
    a = 100+z
}
```

How can I make R store my results as a1, a2,...a10? I know I need to use "paste" and perhaps "assign", but I can't figure it out. Thank you very much for your help!

**Edit:**
Thank you very much for your quick and helpful replies. I now also found a way to make it work (not as nice as yours though):

```
z = 0
while(z<10) {
    z = z+1
    x = 100+z
    assign(paste("a",z, sep=""),x)
}
```

Again, thank you very much!

Cheers,
Chris

Comment: this is really another instance of R FAQ 7.21 ... and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034655/r-how-to-convert-string-to-variable-name

Comment: Is there any particular reason you *need* to create new objects for every result? `a <- 100+1:10` would be just as good, and you can access the elements with very handy subsetting function `[`. It will also be significantly faster.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a while loop to get that vector since you can get it with `100 + 1:10`. Here is a way to assign the values using `mapply`:

```
mapply(assign,value=100+1:10,x=paste0("a",1:10),MoreArgs=list(envir=.GlobalEnv))
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `while` - use `setNames` from the `stats` package:

```
> (function(x)setNames(x,paste(sep="","a",x)))(1:11)
 a1  a2  a3  a4  a5  a6  a7  a8  a9 a10 a11 
  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11
```