# Variable assignment within a for-loop

Tags: r, variable-assignment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [R: How to convert string to variable name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034655/r-how-to-convert-string-to-variable-name)

In R, I'm writing a for-loop that will iteratively create variable names and then assign values to each variable.

Here is a simplified version. The intention is to create the variable's name based on the value of iterating variable i, then fill the new variable with NA values.

(I'm only iterating 1:1 below since the problem occurs isn't related to the looping itself, but rather to the way the variable is being created and assigned.)

```
for (i in 1:1) {

    #name variable i "Variablei"
    varName = paste("Variable", as.character(i), sep="")

    #fill variable with NA values
    varName = rep(NA, 12)

    print(varName)
    print(Variable1)
}
```

Now, varName prints out as

```
 [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

and Variable1 is not found.

I understand on some level why this is buggy. In the first line, varName becomes a vector whose only entry is the string "Variable1". Then varName gets reassigned to hold the NA values. So when I try to print Variable1, it doesn't exist.

I think the more general issue is assignment vs. equality. In the first line, I want varName to *be equal to* the newly made string, but in the next line, I want varName to *be assigned to* the NA value vector.

What is the simplest way of creating that distinction? I'm also open to entirely different, better ways to go about this.

*EDIT: Changed title because I had mischaracterized the problem.*

Comment: You might be better off using a list to hold the values.  Variable <- list(); Variable[[i]] <- rep(NA,12)

Comment: To second @MatthewLundberg's above comment: `lapply(1:1, function(x) rep(NA, 12))`

Comment: This approach seems promising. But the reason I was iterating is because I want to name a large number of variables based on incrementally increasing dates. It seems like I'll still need to go through that for-loop to name the list elements, no?

Comment: No, the reason others are advocating a single structure (a list) is because you can assign attributes, like names, in one line. See `?names`.

Comment: No need to assign names in one line.  No need to add a 'for' loop, and that's because you've already got one.  for (...) { name <- something ; myvariablelist[[name]] <- somevalue }.  (If you can use 'apply' or one of its friends instead of 'for', you should.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assignment works like this:

```
<varname> = <expression>
```

or more traditionally

```
<varname> <- <expression>
```

So, in your code, you have only ever assigned to `varName`. It's not about assignment vs equality, just assignment. You may want to look at `assign`:

```
for (i in 1:5) {
  assign(paste0("Variable", i), 10*i)
}
```

as a toy example.

Moreover, as noted in the comments, there are probably better approaches for your application. For example, why not just use a vector `myvector` and instead of having variables called `Variable1`, `Variable2`, etc you can refer to `myvector[1]`, `myvector[2]` etc.

As an example, let us say you had planned to work with

```
Variable1 <- 'foo'
Variable2 <- 'bar'
Variable3 <- 'baz'
```

then, you could change you approach, and set

```
mydata <- c('foo', 'bar', 'baz')
```

and where you would previously have used `Variable2` (which contains `'bar'`) you instead use `mydata[2]` (which also contains `'bar'`). The point here is that it is much easier to work with vectors and dataframes in R than a long list of variables.

You could go further and name the entries:

```
names(mydata) <- paste0("V", 1:3)
```

which then allows you to write `mydata["V2"]` to retrieve `bar`.

Comment: I'm confused by what you mean in the last sentence. Would myvector be holding variable names? I also added a comment above to clarify why I was iterating through the variables. Thanks.

Comment: Added a bit about names.