# Using a for loop to create multiple lists of different names?

Tags: r, list

I have the following vector

```
years <- c(1996,1997,1998,1999,2000,
           2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010)
```

and I wish to create a list for each number in the vector using a for loop, the name of the list should be the same as the number. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Don't. See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6034703/1385941), especially the link to [R FAQ 7.21](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-can-I-turn-a-string-into-a-variable_003f)

Answer (score 3):

```
yearlist <- setNames(vector(length(years), mode="list"), years)
```