# Use index to name a matrix after a loop in R

Tags: r, matrix

Please excuse my naive question.

I have a loop which returns in every step, a matrix `b`. 
I would like to save each matrix from each loop, under a different name depending on the iteration number. For example, at the end of the first iteration, I want to get the matrix named `b1`, at the end of the second iteration the `b2` etc...

As an example, lets use the following code:

```
count=0
a=matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12), nrow=6)
for (count in 1:10)  {
  b<-cbind(a[,1],matrix(c( a[sample(nrow(a)),2]), nrow=nrow(a)) ) 
  print(b)
}
count+1
```

Here, the original matrix is `matrix a` which has `6` rows and `2` columns.
I permute the order of the elements in the second column. The resulting `matrix b`, is the matrix that conatins as first column the first column of the original `matrix a` and as second column the permuted second column of `a`.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you need them to be separate objects in the workspace? Or would having them all stored in a list be fine?  The list option is probably best.

Comment: As Dason says, a list is a better option. If you *really* need to assign a new variable name, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6034703/509782

Comment: Worth reading: [keep data out of your variable names](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html).

Comment: Dason,I believe that it is better to get them as separate object. My issue is how to assign the names b1,...,b10 to these matrices, so I can use them latter in my code, independently one each other.

Answer (score 3):

You really don't want to store these as separate variables- it would be much better to keep them as a list of 10 matrices. That could be done very easily using `replicate`:

```
lst = replicate(10, cbind(a[,1],matrix(c( a[sample(nrow(a)),2]), nrow=nrow(a)) ),
          simplify=FALSE)
```

You can then access any of the 10 matrices like this:

```
lst[[1]]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    7
#[2,]    2   10
#[3,]    3   11
#[4,]    4    8
#[5,]    5    9
#[6,]    6   12
```

Similarly, you could loop over them like this:

```
for (m in lst) {
    print(m)
    # do something with your matrix m
}
```

Comment: But again, the issue of giving a name to each of these list elements remains. I want to give a name lst1 to the lst[[1]], lst2 to the lst[[2]] etc, so I can use the as separate matrices latter. How can I do that in the loop?

Comment: @DanaiC.: They *are* separate matrices. What do you want to do with ten separate variables that you can't do with this solution? (what's wrong with referring to lst[[1]] instead of referring to lst1?)

Comment: Well, I'm new in programming and my programming causes confusion to other people. So, I'll tell you what's my actual problem. I have a matrix with 747 row and 11 columns. The first column is individuals' ID (I want to keep it as it is) and the rest 10 columns are variables named Y1 to Y10. I want to permute the elements within each of these columns (i.e. permute elements in Y1 column,Y2,...Y10) After that permutation, I need each of these columns separately, to use them in penalized regression. But of course I dont want to do this manually by calling P$Y1, P$Y2 etc. every time, I need a loop.

Comment: @DanaiC.: First, that sounds like a data frame, not a matrix. (You can't access a matrix's column like `P$Y1`. Second, you could simply do a loop over the columns- like `for (j in 2:11)`, and access the column as `P[, j]`. I don't see what that has to do with your question. 3) You might have an easier time if you turned the ID column into rownames- that could be done as `rownames(P) = P[, 1]; P = P[, -1]`. That way the IDs would still stay with the rows but you could treat all columns identically.

Answer (score 1):

As told before, list is a better option. But, if you still want to save each interation on different variables, you can use `assign()`

```
count=0
a=matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12), nrow=6)
for (count in 1:10)  {
  assign(paste('b',count,sep=''),cbind(a[,1],matrix(c( a[sample(nrow(a)),2]), nrow=nrow(a))))
}
b1
b2
```

Answer (score 1):

As said in other option it is better to use a list. Here a version using `sapply` to get pretty named result:

```
 res <- sapply(paste('b',1:10,sep=''), 
           function(x) cbind(a[,1],matrix(c( a[sample(nrow(a)),2]), nrow=nrow(a)) ),
       simplify=F)
```

Then To get matrix `b5` for example,

```
res$b5

   [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    9
[2,]    2    7
[3,]    3    8
[4,]    4   11
[5,]    5   10
[6,]    6   12
```