# Create a list member variable by value

Tags: r

I know that it is possible to create a variable by values. A e.g. is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034655/r-how-to-convert-string-to-variable-name) and [here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/converting-a-string-to-a-variable-name-on-the-fly-and-vice-versa-in-r/). Now I want to know is it possible to create in a similar way the member variable from list a by the value of x?

```
 x<-"name"
 a<-list( [here should place the value of x to declare the variable "name"]=1:5)
```

I dont searching for a workaround like changing dimnames after initialisation, because I like to do it with an S4 object initialisation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this one:

```
    x<-"name"  
    a<-list()  
    a[[x]] <- 1:5
```

### result

```
    > a  
    $name  
    [1] 1 2 3 4 5
```