# Assign name to a substring in a loop importing raster files

Tags: r, raster, rgdal

I'm importing some raster files from a PostgreSQL connection into R in a loop. I want to assign my newly gained rasters automatically to a variable whose name is derived from the input variable like this: `substring(crop, 12)`

```
crop <- "efsa_capri_barley"
ras <- readGDAL(sprintf("PG:dbname='' host='' port='' user='' schema='' table='%s' mode=2", crop))
paste0(substring(crop, 12)) <- raster(ras, 1)
```

What function do I have to use that R recognizes the result of substring() as a character string and not as the function itself? I was thinking about paste() but it doesn't work.
Probably this question has already been asked but I couldn't find a proper answer.

Comment: Duplicate of [R: How to convert string to variable name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034655/r-how-to-convert-string-to-variable-name). I found it by searching for "assign variable name in loop r" in Google.

Comment: yes, you're right. I extended my question.

Comment: Generally on SO you don't ask more than one question at a time. Given that your second question is completely unrelated to the first, I'd delete that and make it a new question. And then if you think @joran answered your first question, I'd go ahead and accept that as correct.

Comment: ok. sounds reasonable. I will ask a new question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your description, `assign` is *technically* correct, but recommending it is bad advice.

If you are pulling in multiple rasters in a loop, best practice in R is to initialize a list to hold *all* the resulting rasters and name each list element accordingly. You can do this one at a time:

```
# n is number of rasters
raster_list <- vector("list",n)

for (i in seq_len(n)){
  ...
  #crop[i] is the ith crop name
  raster_list[[substring(crop[i],12)]] <- raster(...)
}
```

You can also set the names of each element of the list all at once via `setNames`. But you should try to avoid using `assign` pretty much at all costs.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful explanation and without your hint I would have ran into `assign` instantly.

Comment: Maybe it's worth posting a new question or to broaden mine: As each of my rasters (EU (still including the UK^^) wide data) has approx. 200MB and I only need the areal extent of Germany, I wonder if there's a possibility to clip the rasters to my extent when importing / reading them. Can sb think of one?

Comment: instead of n=number of rasters I used n=0, because the code doesn't fill into the list, it appends the rasters to the list.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking for something like `assign`. For example you can try this:

```
assign(substring(crop, 12), raster(ras, 1))
```

To understand how `assign` works, you can check this code:

```
x <- 2
# x is now 2

var_to_assign <- "x"
assign(var_to_assign, 3)
# x is now set to 3
x
# 3
```

Does that give you what you want?