# for loop for creating multiple data frames and assigning values

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

I would like to create multiple data frames and assign them based on years. I have seen other posts but I couldn't duplicate it for my case. 
For example,

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4)
b <- c('kk','km','ll','k3')
time <- (2001,2001,2002,2003)
df <- data.frame(a,b,time)
myvalues <- c(2001,2002,2003)
for (i in 1:3) 
{ y[[i]]<- df[df$time=myvalues[[i]],}
```

I would like to create three dataframes y1, y2, y3 for years 2001, 2002 and 2003. Any suggestions how do using a for loop?

Comment: You have three problems - you need to initialize the list before the loop, `y = list()`, use `==` not `=` for testing equality, and you have unmatched brackets in your loop, `{y[[i]] <-
 df[df$time == myvalues[i],]}`. However instead of the for loop you can just do `y = split(df, df$time)`

Comment: See also [how to make a list of data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/903061) (possible dupe?).

Comment: @Gregor I would say so

Comment: He says he wants 3 dataframes. Not a list of 3 dataframes.

Comment: yes exactly, i was able to get the list from the previous posts and I am looking for individual data frames

Comment: ok, so `list2env(split(df, df$time), .GlobalEnv)`

Comment: (But in all likelihood you *should* want a list of data frames, not individual data frames. There are very few cases where a list is not better and easier to work with than sequentially named variables).

Comment: I need individual ones as I have to carryout some operations on them before combining to a large dataset

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `assign()` function is made for this. See `?assign()` for syntax.

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4)
b <- c("kk","km","ll","k3")
time <- c(2001,2001,2002,2003)
df <- data.frame(a,b,time)
myvalues <- c(2001,2002,2003)

for (i in 1:3) {
  assign(paste0("y",i), df[df$time==myvalues[i],])
  }
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034655/convert-string-to-a-variable-name) for more ways to achieve this.