# removing double quotes from string while passing it as an argument in R

Tags: r, string, function

I have a string with double quotes:
For e.g `string1<-"URL,username,password"`

Now there is one function call:
`function(string1).....` function works if call `function(URl,Username,password)` like this.

But it does not work if I call `function(string1)` like this ,because string1 contains double quotes.

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Please include reproducible example, as well as the error message you get.

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6034655/786542

Comment: @DominicComtois it is a "startGraph" function which connects R to Neo4j(the Graph Database). It takes 3 arguments 1. URL 2.username and 3.password. Its actually a inbuilt function of library RNeo4j. So, if i pass URL, username and password separately inside the startGraph function it works but if I save URL,username and password to an object and pass that object to startGraph function , it doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear about what/how the function responds.  Here, is an example that takes two arguments for parameters for the dataset and the column name and get the `mean` of that column

```
f1 <- function(dat, col){
     mean(dat[[col]], na.rm = TRUE)

}

df <- data.frame(col1 = 1:5)
f1(df, "col1")
#[1] 3
```

If we create the function with a single parameter that takes string as an argument, then split the string by the delimiter (`,`), `get` the value of the dataframe object, subset the column and apply the `mean` function

```
f2 <- function(str1){
      v1 <- strsplit(str1, ",")[[1]]
      mean(get(v1[1])[[v1[2]]], na.rm = TRUE)
  }

string1 <- "df,col1"
f2(string1)
#[1] 3
```

Comment: it is  a "startGraph" function which connects R to Neo4j(the Graph Database). It takes 3 arguments 1. URL 2.username and 3.password. Its actually a inbuilt function of library RNeo4j. So, if i pass URL, username and password separately inside the  startGraph function it works but if I save URL,username and password to an object and pass that object to startGraph function , it doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is `do.call`:

```
args <- as.list(strsplit(x = "a,b,c", split = ",")[[1]])
do.call(someFunction, args)
```