# Assign into variable from string

Tags: r, rlang, tidyeval, quasiquotes

I would like to dynamically create a variable name from a string and then assign in a value. I believe I should be able to easily do this with `{rlang}` but haven't been able to work it out from package docs, [Advanced R](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/expressions.html), and searching. Below is a pseudo-reprex of what I'm looking for. Thank you for your guidance!

My desired output: `answer <- 42`

My input: `x <- "answer"` (except that "answer" is generated and not hardcoded in the script)

Attempt: `rlang::sym(x) <- 42`

Comment: `assign(x, 42)`? If you need this, your whole approach is bad practice and should be changed.

Comment: I think this is the relevant duplicate  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034655/convert-string-to-a-variable-name

Answer (score 0):

Is `answer <- 42` your desired *output*, or your desired *effect*?

If it's the desired output, inject the `answer` symbol in a defused expression with `expr()`

```
expr(!!sym(x) <- 42)
#> answer <- 42

answer
#> Error: object 'answer' not found
```

If you need to evaluate this expression, use `inject()`:

```
inject(!!sym(x) <- 42)

answer
#> [1] 42
```