# How to create variables through a vector in R

Tags: r, loops, vector

I am using RStudio 2022.12.0 and I would like to create variable names through a vector of strings.

My vector is:

```
names <- c("John", "Mike", "Tom", "Ben", "Nathalia", "Stephanie")
```

I was trying to use a look to create a varable name from every name in the vektor.

```
for (x in names)
{x <- print(paste("The name is", x))}
```

This produces the following error msg:

```
Error in print(paste(x)) <- print(paste("The name is", x)) :could not find function "print<-"
```

```
    If i change the code to
    for (x in names){
    x <- print(paste("The name is", x))
    }
```

it prints:

```
\[1\] "The name is John"

\[1\] "The name is Mike"

\[1\] "The name is Tom"

\[1\] "The name is Ben"

\[1\] "The name is Nathalia"

\[1\] "The name is Stephanie"
```

But I do not get 6 variable named John, Mike, ..., Stepganie.

[image]

I would be please if anybody could help me.

Thank you

```
    for (x in names){
      x <- print(paste("The name is", x))
    }
```

I expected to get something like

> ```
> John <- c("The name is John")
> ```

Comment: `print` doesn't have return value.  So you can't assign.  You may need to store the output in a vector or list i.e. `x1 <- character(length(names)); for(i in seq_along(names)) x1[i] <- paste("The name is", names[i])`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert string to a variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034655/convert-string-to-a-variable-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @akrun states, you aren’t indexing your loop properly. His correct recommendation will give you a variable `x` of length 6 each with “The name is *whatever name*” However if you truly want something like:

```
John <- c("The name is John")
```

You can use `assign` to output the name as an object in the global environment. You can do both in the same loop:

```
nnames <- c("John", "Mike", "Tom", "Ben", "Nathalia", "Stephanie")

x <- c()
for (i in nnames){
    x[i]<- paste("The name is", i)
    assign(i, x[i])
}
#test
x
John
Tom
```

Note I changed `names` to `nnames` since it is not good practice to name things after inherent functions in R (`names` is already a base R function)